# DropDown menu in uinavigationbar

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu, uinavigationbar

Any thoughts about a dropdown menu in the navigation bar in iOS like the one shown in these pictures?

[dropdown closed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVJVn.png)

[dropdown opened image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrxiC.png)

Answer (score -1):

here is what I was using (I am not an author).

https://github.com/nmattisson/DropdownMenu

[image: drop down menu]

and another one 
https://github.com/eternityz/RWDropdownMenu

[image: drop down menu - 2]